# Googleusercontent breaking image links in newsletter

Tags: caching, mailing

We send automatic emails to our customers.
Google is rewriting the email's image links and completely breaking them, giving a 404 error

Google is rewriting to:

https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lVDjm7qabVoI9h7Coj2diPm68n9EGr70vaBDLDFWRsy4fPRbABMENW-f24JPGUgCWLdw7bPE5RvA5me4D9vVsS_pec0Xpc1uheArG_tIGk71Hjs=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.example.com/image.png

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFdyj.png)

So there is something wrong with the links that are being created by Google or the images are just not being uploaded to the googleusercontent server, but I have no idea how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling, I discovered a solution for google injecting its own proxy server image URL.

For me, it was hosting the image privately (on my own server) that was causing the problem. After hosting the image publicly (on Mailchimp's Content Manager, for example) I was able to serve my images much more reliably.

I really hope this helps as it was causing me all kinds of problems.

Good luck!